# How to get an alert when my input volume is turned on and turn it off if I so desire?

Tags: gnome, sound, scripts, software-recommendation, input-devices

As you can tell by the name, I am an extra paranoid Panda and in order to keep my bamboo safe I don't want my input volume to be on just in case if I get some spyware which listens to my sound input. Basically I just want to be as safe as possible so that no other Panda listens in on my Panda bamboo secrets (where I put it all).

So basically this is what I want, a script which:

- Checks whether or not the input volume for my microphone (or any sound input devices) is on 0% at regular intervals
- Alerts me via `notify-send` every 5 minutes if it is on
- An option within the script (like a boolean or something) which is not on by default, but if it is turned on will make it so that when the input volume is on I will be alerted that it was on and has been turned off, and for the script obviously also (probably before alerting me) to turn the input volume off
- Is able to scan multiple input sources so that for instance if I have 2 microphones, 1 is muted, but the other not, it does not just assume that all is well

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18. How can this be done? I don't expect there to be one (that's why I'm asking for a script), but if there is an application which can do this, then please recommend it.

Comment: If I can find a reliable way to get the input volume of all input devices, the rest is easy :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm: You could do some clever grepping with the output of `pactl list sources`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple script that scans a given pulseaudio input source for being muted<sup>*</sup>.

The source can be given as pulseaudio source index number as can be listed with:

```
pactl list sources
```

If the source was not muted a warning message will be displayed in a desktop notification.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Forces a pulseaudio source to be muted
#
# Usage:
# micmute <source> <wait> <--force>
# <source>: pulseaudio source index number
# <wait>: seconds to wait for checking
# <--force>: force muting microphone and notify
source="$1"
wait="$2"
force="$3"

echo "Scanning input #$source every $wait seconds."

while true; do
    if ! (pactl list sources | sed -n '/^Source #'"$source"'/,/^$/p' | grep "Mute: yes"); then
        if [[ $force == "--force" ]]; then
            pactl set-source-mute $source 1
            notify-send "Muting input $source"
        else
            notify-send "WARNING - input $source is not muted"
        fi
    fi
    sleep $wait  ## CLI option seconds to wait
done
```

Save that script with any name (e.g. `micmute`) and give it executable permission. The script then may be called with

```
./micmute <source> <wait> [--force]
```

`<source>` is the index number of the microphone source to be scanned.
`<wait>` will define the time in seconds after which we repeat our query for a muted source device.
`--force` is an optional flag to force muting of our source.

---

For me the following **example** line will query the mute state of my microphone (index `2`) every 5 minutes, and it will forcedly mute it if it was unmuted.

```
./micmute 2 300 --force
```

---

<sup>* I preferred muting over setting the volume to `0` because of the advantage to restore the previous volume settings on unmuting.</sup>

Comment: So if I had two microphones, one muted, and the other not, would it just assume that all was well?

Comment: It's a good answer you have posted, however I am sorry but as it doesn't fully match my specifications I cannot accept it in its current state, though I have given it an upvote.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: see edit for a script that queries a given source only. To listen to two or more sources at the same time run it multiple times with different parameters.